# Strange visits on a specific page of my site

Tags: bots, spam-prevention

Recently I developed a script in order to log the visits of my site.

I noticed that many times per day there are some strange visits. The visits are related with a specific page of my site and come from sites like the ones in the list below:

- nayra.ru
- zl-news.ru
- bizlog.ru
- opel.barsavto.ru
- tovray.ru
- www.vk-mail-hack.com
- danelkon.net/news.php?readmore=74
- pronekut.com
- www.wallpapers.su
- pornogig.com
- spb.ceramic.ru
- zl-news.ru
- renkele.net
- ublaze.ru
- mug-na-chas-moscow.ru

Does anyone know what they are trying to do with these visits? Are they any spam bots or attempts?

Comment: What server do you host on your site?  What's the difference between this page and the others?  Maybe they are bots probing the sw of your site for known vulnerabilities.

Comment: Is a linux server! The specific page has just static text, not forms or other contents! Is there a way to prevent them?

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is that most of these visits have referrals that smell strange. If you check them you will be redirected to a page and seems that this is the bot's intention, to gather visits thru the referrals, so simply ignore them.